# Finding the stability of the system

Tags: signal-analysis, impulse-response, homework

> Determine whether the system $h(n)=nu(n)$ is BIBO stable or not.

I have solved it and got it as unstable as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \lvert h(n)\rvert = \infty$. But the book ¹ is saying stable:

[image: solution from book]

Which one is correct?

---

[¹](https://books.google.com.np/books?id=ytuUKKVeR88C&lpg=PP1&pg=PT65#v=onepage&q&f=true): S. Poornachandra, B. Sasikala: Digital Signal Processing. Third Ed. McGraw Hill, New Delhi

Comment: Which book? Can you add a scan of that example (and its answer) to the question?

Comment: https://books.google.com.np/books?id=ytuUKKVeR88C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false,page 59 qno.4)

Comment: The solution from the book contradicts itself, and proves it's unstable. Just a typo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just based on a typo in the book, with the correct statement given directly above the typo. Hence, this question holds no value for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

That's a (copy-paste) mistake in the book. The result in the given example is that the sum doesn't converge, yet the author concludes that the system is stable, which is obviously wrong:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|h[n]|=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n=\infty$$

The system is **not** BIBO-stable.